# Create aro/aco having an aro and an aco

Tags: cakephp, permissions, acl

I'm trying to implement PDF functionality to my application. So, I added some new actions in controllers (like 'viewpdf').
After this, I rebuild the ACL tree with the build_acl action (from Mark Story Tutorial [Automated tool for creating ACOS](http://book.cakephp.org/view/647/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs#!/view/647/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs) ).
So, I can see with MySQL that a new node is created.
Until this, everything is fine. But now I try to test the viewpdf button, and I get a 'You are not authorized to access that location.' error (even being admin). I check the error.log file and I see a warning:

```
> Aco: controllers/Specializations/viewpdf in [/usr/share/php/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php, line 273]
2011-02-24 11:40:34 Warning: Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [email] => admin@gmail.com
            [group_id] => 1
        )

)

Aco: controllers/Specializations/viewpdf in [/usr/share/php/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php, line 273]
```

Then I check the aros_acos table in the database and I see that there's no 'viewpdf' ACO related to any node, so there's an ARO, an ACO, but not an ARO_ACO, so I suppose that this is the reason why I'm getting this error.

¿Are my suppositions right? If they are, how could I create this aro_aco? I'm afraid that I could break anything if I do it manually...

Thanks in advance,

Alf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alfizqu,

if you have an ARO and an ACO but no connection between these by means of entries in the ACO_ARO table, this means you have not set up the permissions your AROs have on the ACOs.

Proceed like this:

```
/*
 * Copied from the tutorial, and modified, this function initializes the per-
 * missions for accessing controller actions.
 */
  function initDB() {
    $group =& $this->User->Group;

    // A D M I N S
    $group->id = 3;     
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    // M A N A G E R S
    $group->id = 2;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Items','*'); ... ...
```

Once you have set up such an initDB function, you have to run it once by calling it from your browser.
If this does not suffice to help you back on the track, just go over the basic AUTH/ACL tutorial again.
Yours, Benjamin.

**Edit 1:**
One of the crucial points is to call the `parent::beforeFilter()` in the `beforeFilter()` methods of self-defined controllers and properly setting up the `app_controller`.
If these tips do not help, the most time-efficient way is to go over the ACL/AUTH tutorial *very* carefully, starting from a fresh cake environment. Once you can get it up and running there, you are confident to do it in your app.

**Edit 2:**
And don't be afraid to throw out everything ACL/AUTH related of your app. It just sounds daunting, but it can safe a lot of debugging headaches/time.

P.S.: Btw there should be some moderately usable ACL/AUTH plugins at the bakery and one at sourceforge.

Comment: After thinking about it, I think that the problem is not aros_acos, because then u would be right, but the point is that I'm running everytime initDB() after build_acl. So, after checking again aros_acos table, I think that it's OK. Now I'm pretty lost, any other ideas? Thank you , btw!

Comment: as it seems you are doing it somehow right, you can follow my edits 1 and 2. Before that, I would double check if it is not simply a filename issue (view_pdf? viewpdf). This could be indicated if you created this action recently and you are able to access other actions properly. Yours -

Comment: Yes, I'm an idiot. My action in the controller was viewPdf (the capital letter...). I'm so sorry for taking your time, I would like to vote you up but I don't have enough reputation. :(. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: alfizqu, i am glad we made it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an sample action in users controller like this

```
function install(){
     $aco = new Aco();
     $aco->create();
     $aco->save(array(
         'parent_id' => <Id of the Specializations in acos table>,
     'alias' => 'viewpdf',
     ));


    $this->Acl->allow('admin','controllers/Specializations/viewpdf','*');
}
```

If u run the action the a new Aco node will be created in acos table. and for the admin user u can give the whole permission.you can use any valid user (username should be in Aros table) instead admin.

hope it helps.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I think that finally aros_acos table is well set up , so now I don't know where's the problem! Thanks for ur answer!